# How to generate apk file for cordova mobile app developed in Mobile First 8.0?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to install my app in different android devices and so I want to generate apk file of my app.

Note:
There is no hooks folder when I create a Application.

[image]

I have:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
Windows 7

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 you create Cordova apps **using the Cordova CLI**, and you **add to it** the MobileFirst Foundation Cordova plugin (the MobileFirst Foundation SDK).

Since you create standard Cordova apps, you also create the .apk using the Cordova CLI.

Learn how to add the MobileFirst Foundation SDK to your Cordova application: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adding-the-mfpf-sdk/cordova/

Learn more about the Cordova CLI: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

The `cordova build` command generates the .apk, by default in debug mode (unsigned apk)

Depending on your needs you'll need to build it in debug or release modes.

If you prefer development in Eclipse, make sure to install the MobileFirst Eclipse plug-in as well as the THyM plug-in, as instructed here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/

Comment: I develop using eclipse IDE.What I have to do??

Comment: Read tutorials?? https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/

Comment: yes I have installed THym plugin and mobile first studio plugin but I what I have to actual do to get the apk .

Comment: You need to run the Cordova build command, which generates an APK. Read the Cordova documentation.

Comment: So I have to develop the app in eclipse and generate apk  through cmd...Am I right?

Comment: ..please check the edited question and provide me a solution !!

Comment: Right-click on the app and select Run As -> on device. This also generates an apk. However you need to go to the Cordova documentation and learn how to create the apks for your production. This is not related to MobileFirst.

Comment: To be frank... your document does not provide any information for beginners and using mobile first in eclipse gives worst experiences...

Comment: Again, in v8.0 there is no relation between building your application to MobileFirst. In v8.0 you build **Cordova apps** hence you' need to use **Cordova tooling**. The MobileFirst plugin only provides functionality that relates to MobileFirst, like preview and register. If you want to build your app, you need to use Cordova tooling. You may call this "worst experience", but perhaps you need to realize that **it does not relate to mobilefirst**.